# Im new to React, can someone tell me why is this happening...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code

```
import React from "react"

let x = 0;

const App = () => {
  x++;
  console.log(x)

  return(
    <div>
      <p>{x}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The console shows 1...but the page shows 2...

How is possible that the code inside the function executes twice(Apparently the x++ runs twice) and the console only outputs one time (1)

Comment: Not sure exactly why this is happening, but as a general rule only use `state` properties in your react components.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, I get 1 in both places. Are you sure this is exactly the code you're running?

Comment: I don't see any problem here, you may want to try it again as something else is making this happen for sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be caused by rendering your app in `React.StrictMode`, it causes dual-renders in development mode. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html. It also suppresses `console` calls on subsequent renders, which may explain the difference you're seeing:

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods
> like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in certain cases where a workaround can be used.